# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.10 with Wubi in windows 7 - Wubi is stuck

Tags: wubi

I tried installing using Wubi. It is stuck at the "1 hr remaining"-message for several hours. The same has happened in previous 4-6 installation attempt. What could be the problem?

Comment: Probably the servers are overloaded. Try downloading the ISO yourself using a bittorrent client and save it in the same directory as wubi.exe before running. Or try again later

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**This question was answered in a comment.** (While the situation here may have been temporary, it's the sort of thing that recurs, so I believe this is valuable as an answer.)</sup>

> Probably the servers are overloaded. Try downloading the ISO yourself
>   using a bittorrent client and save it in the same directory as
>   wubi.exe before running. Or try again later.

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Oct 19 '12 at 19:59](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203175/unable-to-install-ubuntu-12-10-with-wubi-in-windows-7-wubi-is-stuck#comment252829_203175)